# How to set CommandBar under SplitView?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-10

I'm developing an application for Windows 10 Platform.
While developing this application, I ran into an issue where `CommandBar` is above `SplitView`.

How do I set `CommandBar` under `SplitView` under controls on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPROVED**

Due to I was making for my own app, here is the study and solution I elaborate here: http://bit.ly/1L6EZ00. It involves changes in many parts and I think it looks cool.

**Old**, in case you just need only that:

That is most similar behavior like the photos app that I have been capable to achieve (it is like the lottery testing):

```
<Page.TopAppBar >
<CommandBar  Margin="48,0,0,0"   >
    <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Globe"  Label="Quick Launch" Command="{Binding QuickLaunch}">
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

Now the splitview:

```
 <SplitView x:Name="Splitter" Margin="0,-48,0,0"  CompactPaneLength="48" OpenPaneLength="240" ...
```

then pane as usual and the content, for instance:

```
 <SemanticZoom  Margin="0,48,0,0">
```

It is not exactly the same as the Photos apps and I am using the 10166 SDK so I think it is the most accurate option.